# bxslider text effects animate.css

Tags: jquery, css, animation, bxslider

I'm currently setting up a slider for my website and I ran into some problems.

I use [bxslider](http://bxslider.com) and I wanted to add animations for the text in each slide by adding [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). Animate.css is pretty simple: just add "animated" and the animation name as classes to the animated element.

Basically, I want text to appear on a slide with an animation after the slider finished the transition to the slide. I also want the text to fade out before the transition to the next slide with the next text.

Since the slider has callback-functions I thought it would be straightforward to just add the necessary CSS-classes through.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".bxslider").bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        startSlide: 0,
        slideWidth: 640,
        onSlideAfter: function(){
        $(".title").addClass("animated bounceInRight");
        $(".text").addClass("animated bounceInRight");
        },
        onSlideBefore: function(){
        $(".title").removeClass("animated bounceInRight");
        $(".text").removeClass("animated bounceInRight");
        }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="" />
<h1 class="title animated bounceInRight">TITLE 1</h1><p class="text animated bounceInRight">
  text text text text text text
  text text text text text text

 </p></li>
  <li><img src="" /><h1 class="title">TITLE 2</h1><p class="text">
  text text text text text text
  text text text text text text

 </p></li>
  <li><img src="" /><h1 class="title">TITLE 3</h1><p class="text">
  text text text text text text
  text text text text text text

 </p></li>
  <li><img src="" /><h1 class="title">TITLE 4</h1><p class="text">
  text text text text text text
  text text text text text text

 </p></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS 1** (what I added to the slider's default CSS)

```
.bxslider {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.title {
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left: 100px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
.text {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    left: 200px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    width: 300px;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* to delay text "entrance" */

}
```

**CSS 2** (animation "trigger"... the different animations are just CSS3 animations with keyframes and so on)

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

I put an example slider online: [bxslider test](http://ap2k.de/bxslider).

There are several problems so far. I will always refer to "text", but I mean both the `<h1>` and the `<p>` tags.

**First**: The first slide is animated correctly, the text appears with animations. On the second slide, the text is already visible and then the animation starts. I want the text to appear "through" the animation.

**Second**: I tried adding the fadeOut-effect (again by adding and removing the corresponding CSS-classes). It won't work, the fadeOut will happen after the transition to the next slide. I guess I make some fundamental mistake with adding and removing the classes, but I can't figure it out.

**Third**: Could I use different entrance-effects on each slide, maybe even randomly?

**Fourth**: There seems to be a bug in Safari. On my computer (Safari & Chrome) the slideshow starts with the first slide. On the webserver in Safari, the last slide is visible first and then it srolls  through the first slide directly to the second slide... very strange. In Chrome the slideshow looks normal. There are no problems with the code according to Safari's log

It would be really nice if someone could help me out with this, at least for the first two problem.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful if you wrote the code **ON** the post. It is rare that someone would open up your test website to check the code. Just saying.

Comment: I posted the code... the only thing necessary is the jQuery... the website is just to illustrate the problem. Or what code do you think is necessary?

Comment: Not really. The CSS and the HTML are important also. For instance, I could suggest that you set the `display: none` for the container of the texts to solve your first problem, but I'm not entirely sure what they are and what CSS is currently applied.

Comment: I added the CSS and the HTML. I hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: try wrapping the `h1` and `p` inside a DIV, set this DIV's CSS to `display: none` and run. I think the animation sets its visibility back

Comment: I did the following: `.bxslider div {display:none;}` and wrapped `<h1>` and `<p1>` in a `<div>`-container. It doesn't show the text anymore.

Answer (score 3):

**How to do it:**

**HTML:**

```
<section class="slider">  
    <ul class="bxslider" >
        <li><img src="foto-1.jpg"/>
            <div class="one slider-text">your text</div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="foto-2.jpg"/>
        <div class="slider-text">your text 2</div>
        </li>       
        <li><img src="foto-3.jpg"/>
        <div class="slider-text">your text3 </div>
        </li>                    
    </ul>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider .slider-text {
    font-size: 250%;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 20%;
    width: 100%;  
}
.slider-text {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.slider-text.active-slide {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    preloadImages: 'all',
    mode: 'horizontal',
    captions: false,
    controls: false,
    pause: 5000,
    speed: 800,
    onSliderLoad: function () {
        $('.bxslider>li .slider-text').eq(1).addClass('active-slide');
        $(".slider-text.active-slide").addClass("wow animated bounceInRight");
    },
    onSlideAfter: function (currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
        console.log(currentSlideHtmlObject);
        $('.active-slide').removeClass('active-slide');
        $('.bxslider>li .slider-text').eq(currentSlideHtmlObject + 1).addClass('active-slide');
        $(".slider-text.active-slide").addClass("wow animated bounceInRight");

    },
    onSlideBefore: function () {
        $(".slider-text.active-slide").removeClass("wow animated bounceInRight");
        $(".one.slider-text.active-slide").removeAttr('style');

    }
});
```

**I use:**
BxSlider v4.1.2  
jQuery v1.11.2 
Latest Animate.css

**You  may use to:**
wow.js

Comment: welcome to SO! it may also be worthwhile to explain to OP what the issue with their code was

Comment: I'm not good at English but...

at the moment  code work this way.

When the slide is active, add class active-slide to div class=slider-text.

If the slide is active, animated text is switched on.

The other slids is not active <div class = "slider-text"> animation is disabled and div is hidden.

After switch to the next slide div becomes active ( by add  class active-slide to a div with class= slider-text ) and re-play animation from begin.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use wow js and add classes normaly then
reinitialise wow each time

```
$(document).ready(function(){
new WOW().init();
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
auto: true,
adaptiveHeight: true,
onSlideAfter: function () {
new WOW().init();
},
onSlideBefore: function () {

new WOW().init();
}


});

});
```